# Data Loader wizard pages in Oracle APEX 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We need to use the Data Loading Wizard pages for many tables. Is there a way to define the underlying table programatically? I don't want to create 4 pages for each table.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't change the target dynamically for the data load wizard. I can suggest 3 options for you to consider:

1. Create the data load wizards for each table, as you mentioned - although it's a bit of work up front, it's not that hard (esp. when compared with the alternatives).
2. Roll your own solution. Get a CSV parser (e.g. from the Alexandria PL/SQL Library) and create the Apex pages to allow the user to map columns in the CSV to the table columns. I think this would be quite a challenge.
3. Create a temporary table with all the columns from all the target tables. Create a single Data Load Wizard for that table. Write some extra logic to take the resulting data and copy it to the target tables. I've used this approach in a recent project that needed to insert/update rows in dozens of different tables in the schema, and it worked reasonably well - but it wasn't simple.

Comment: If you're going with option 3, which is what I've used in a previous project, I suggest that you ditch the wizard and leverage AJAX functionality so that you can have the user interact in just one page when loading tables from a file (as opposed to several pages using the wizard). This will do wonders for your user experience.